# Problema al armar consulta con ORM DJANGO

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

Tengo estas clases de modelos

```
class PriceHistory(models.Model):
id_ml = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
price = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Property(SoftDeletionModel)

id_ml= models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)  
city= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)  
state= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)  
country= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Estoy usando esta consulta

```
results = PriceHistory.objects.filter( id_ml__id_ml = self.id_ml).select_related('id_ml').exclude(price=self.price).order_by('-created').distinct()
```

Me está costando encontrar la forma de que en la consulta anterior filtre por la class Property where country, state y city sean igual a "Argentina" "Buenos Aires" "La Plata"

Como podria hacer que results imprima esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con

```
results = PriceHistory.objects.filter(id_ml__city="La Plata", id_ml__state="Buenos Aires", id_ml__country="Argentina")
```

Te recomiendo poner nombres más descriptivos a las variables, para que puedas comprenderlas mejor. Pro ejemplo yo pondría

```
class PriceHistory(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # comprendes mejor que se relaciona con el modelo property
```